# Remove Cart Items Automatically Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

I'm having a trouble with my Magento 2 store. I need to clear all items of users carts programmatically.

If user don't purchase his cart, it'll be cleaned.

Do you have any idea of how can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Byron**, I guess that you need to clear the [**Abandoned Carts**](https://www.optimizely.com/optimization-glossary/shopping-cart-abandonment/) from your system.
As per **Abandoned Cart** concept if **A shipping cart** is   In-active is sudden time, then it becomes called Abandoned Cart.

At Magento, if anything update happens then the update_at of quote table will update at.

So, **you need to get a quote collection where `updated_at` field value 24hrs before.**
 and using cron clear that quote collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
 */
protected $cart;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

public function execute()
{
    // Truncate the cart items
    $this->cart->truncate();
}
```